# Where can I download 30x 1000 genomes cram files?

Tags: wgs, 1000genomes

From the preprint published by 1000 genome project (https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.02.06.430068v1.full) I think the 30x data is for WGS. Can anyone confirm for me if the following file is really WGS data?
ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/run/ERR324/ERR3242643/HG03007.final.cram.
Also, Is there any more freely available sequencing data where I can find WGS data for 30x and low coverage(<10x) for the same sample for the South Asian population?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those are the .cram files for the 30x whole genome sequencing data for 1000 genomes.

If you want 10x and 30x sequence data for the same individual, you can just downsample the 30x .cram file using `samtools view -s`.

Comment: 30x WGS or WES? Can u specify it in your answer?

Comment: WGS - I don't know why you'd think it was exome sequencing - there's no mention of that in the paper or the website.

Comment: There is actually. But that was at the depth of 65.7x coverage. However, I asked just to be sure, anyway once again thanks for your answer.